# SignalR - Detect disconnected client in no time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

I am working on an application that needs to recognize when someone log's off from system.
I've set ping interval to 5 seconds. I also have `public override Task OnConnected()` and `public override Task OnDisconnected()`, and they are triggered each time client connects and disconnects (I remember clients names and connections while connecting, and remove those data from list when disconnected)

So, when a client log's off the system, his connection is lost and he doesn't send any ping response. I have this solution working, but when it takes too much time, around 30 seconds to run `OnDisconnected` function. 
Is there any possibility to make this process faster? I have to detect this in at least 4-5 seconds.

EDIT: here is the code
**Hub.cs:**

```
public class SignalRConnection
    {
        public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
public static List<SignalRConnection> connections = new List<SignalRConnection>();
public override Task OnConnected()
        {            
            connections.Add(new SignalRConnection() { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId, UserName=Context.User.Identity.Name});
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            var forDelete = connections.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
            connections.Remove(forDelete);           
            Clients.All.logoffActions(forDelete.UserName);
            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
```

**Global.asax**

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout =TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);            
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
```

Comment: Your `OnDisconnected` method takes 30 seconds to run?! Post the code for it please and also where you are storing the connections.

Comment: I've set DisconnectTimeout to 6 seconds, and now it triggeres event in approximatly 8-10 seconds. 6 seconds is minimum value for DisconnectTimeout. I've edited original question with code.

Comment: Do you know what part is taking so long? I can see some performance improvements by using a `Hashset<T>` for the connections. But i'm still not 100% sure what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect what happens from javascript. This will help understanding what happens with the connection: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Basically first, your connection goes in `reconnecting` state (can be slow connection, short interruption in connection ... ) In this state tries to connect again. By default 6 times every 5 seconds, which takes 30 seconds. If no success fires the `disconnected` event which is going to call your hub's  `OnDisconnected` method.

You can use the reconnecting function in javascript, but in this state, client can still come back.

You can use something like this is JS:

```
var tryingToReconnect = false;

$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = true;
});

$.connection.hub.reconnected(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = false;
});

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
    if(tryingToReconnect) {
        notifyUserOfDisconnect(); // Your function to notify user.
    }
});
```

When the connection is down `$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {` will be called instantly, (but the firing of this event doesn't always mean that the connection is down! It might just be a quick connection problem)

Another useful thing would be the `connectionSlow` event.

```
$.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function() {
    notifyUserOfConnectionProblem(); // Your function to notify user.
});
```

Most importantly to understand the states and the transitions described in the linked description.

I hope it helps. Cheers!